# Trying to auto select multiple options in jade data from mongo

Tags: node.js, html, mongodb, pug

'data' represents the current selected pet
'pets' represents all the pets in MongoDB
trying to select the pets that have been previously selected as conflicts

```
label.col-sm-3.control-label(for='petConflicts') Pet Conflicts
.col-sm-7
 select.form-control(name='petConflicts', multiple=true)
  each pet, index in pets
   option(value=pet._id, selected=data.petConflicts[index]===pet._id) #{pet.name}
```

was kinda going off

```
    label.radio.col-sm-3
      input(type='radio', name='gender', checked=data.gender=='male', value='male', data-toggle='radio')
      span Male
    label.radio.col-sm-3
      input(type='radio', name='gender', checked=data.gender=='female', value='female', data-toggle='radio')
      span Female
```

witch works great am i missing something is it possible to auto select multiple options on ?

Answer (score 0):

```
          if data.petConflicts.indexOf(pet._id) > -1
            option(value=pet._id, selected=true) #{pet.name}
          else
            option(value=pet._id, selected=false) #{pet.name}
```

or

```
      select.form-control(name='plan')
        option(value=1, selected=data.plan===1) Once a week
        option(value=2, selected=data.plan===2) Twice a week
        option(value=3, selected=data.plan===3) Three times a week
        option(value=4, selected=data.plan===4) Four times a week
        option(value=5, selected=data.plan===5) Five times a week
        option(value=6, selected=data.plan===6) Six times a week
        option(value=7, selected=data.plan===7) Every day
```

both ended up working for me.